# Online ticket benefits, Madame Tussauds New York

Tags: tickets, sightseeing, new-york-city

What are the benefits of Madame Tussauds online ticket purchasing as compared to walk up tickets? Also I see that there is a concession for Local Residents. I am staying in New York for 4 years with a visa.

Am I eligible for the Local Resident concession as well? What are the documents I need to carry to show my residency as a visa holder?

Comment: The normal way to show residency is with a valid New York driver's license or non-driver ID, showing an address within the city.  I expect an [idnyc](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/idnyc/index.page) card would also work. Do you have one of those?  They almost surely don't care about your visa status.

Comment: If you're a student, a student ID. Otherwise, a utility bill might work.

Comment: @NateEldredge No I don't have a car and New York driver's license. I have a college Id and my college situated in New York.

Comment: @mkennedy Yes I have a student Id. How could a student Id reduce my ticket fee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only difference is knowing you have a ticket for that date, where as walk ups could have to wait if the venue is at capacity